# Go: Taking the address of Map Members

Tags: pointers, dictionary, go

Can someone explain why r contains two entires of the same address?

```
r := make([]*Result, len(m))
i := 0
for _, res := range m {
    fmt.Println("index, result:", i, *&res)
    r[i] = &res
    i++
}
fmt.Println(r)
```

Results in:

```
index, result: 0 {[] map[0:1 1:1] {port=6379}}
index, result: 1 {[] map[0:1 1:1] {port=6380}}
[0xc21010d6c0 0xc21010d6c0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*Result` as the map value. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Result struct{}

func main() {
    m := make(map[string]*Result)
    r := make([]*Result, 0, len(m))
    for _, res := range m {
        fmt.Println("index, result:", len(r), *res)
        r = append(r, res)
    }
    fmt.Println(r)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `res` is given at each iteration of the loop.

The fact you have the same address only means that point in memory is reused.

Comment: Ah that make sense, do you have a suggested rewrite for the desired output?

Comment: What's the desired output ?

Comment: Convert all the values of map m (map[string]Result) to a slice of Result pointers

Comment: I don't think a map gives you any kind of guarantee regarding the validity of those addresses. So it's possible you can't get them. If you want to give addresses, I think you have to extract the values, you can't directly point in the map.

Comment: So I guess I can put them directly intermediate array, and then loop over the array and take the pointers from there ... icky :-P